# i need to print numbers in pl sql in the given format?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, printform

I need to print numbers in pl/sql in the given format?

```
1
1 2 
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

also can you tell me how to print the next two commands in the same line in the output screen.

```
dbms_output.put_line(j);
dbms_output.put_line(j+1);
```

Comment: the format is 1 \n 1 2 \n 1 2 3\n 1 2 3 4..\n depicts new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print multiple outputs on the same line, use `dbms_output.put` instead of `dbms_output.put_line`.

*CAVEAT* When using `dbms_output.put`, you have to flush the buffer afterwards - otherwise, your output won't appear on the screen.

Your original question can be solved by using two for loops:

```
begin
  for i in 1 .. 10
  loop
    for j in 1 .. i
    loop
      dbms_output.put(to_char(j) || ' ');
    end loop;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in plain SQL instead of PL/SQL as follows:

```
select to_char(sum(res) over(order by res)) as res
  from ( select sum(power(10, level - 1)) over(order by level) as res
           from dual
        connect by level <= 5 )
```

Result:

```
RES
--------------------
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

`To_char()` function is used just to align result to the left.